# SSL communication between a C# Server and an Android Client App

Tags: java, c#, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using a C# server and a C# tcp client example I extracted from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I have created a self signed certificate using makecert.exe. I have got this to communicate with one another and it seems to be working fine. Similarly I want to build an android tcp client that will communicate with the C# server. Do I need to create a certificates for the client or anything of that sort? If I do how do I import it in to android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the certificates that I created in to a java key store and used it on the android client side which worked for me. Following link will give anyone an insight in to creating the certificates which I found very useful.  [Click](http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/)